# Python detect font in txt file

Tags: python, fonts

I wrote some text in txt file. I know how to read from that file but how can I print font in which the text is written? Using python. Thanks

Comment: plain txt files do not contain such information.

Answer (score 1):

A txt file has no information about fonts. The font you see is the font of your editor. If you need the name of the font check the editor.